# VIBORITA/SNAKE ..juego desarrollado en una matriz: no imprime con las modificaciones de filas y columnas

Tags: c

imprime siempre la matriz y la vibora en la posicion inicial que establecí, no se mueve.
Pensé que con las lineas como las siguientes estoy modificando el numero de filas y columnas, pero no me imprime la viborita con las filas o columnas modificadas, no se si estoy accediendo y modificando correctamente de esta forma las filas y columnas de la matriz.:

```
           cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila+1;  //mueve cabeza
           cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
           for(i=0;i<longitud_cuerpo;i++){
           cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila+1;  //mueve cuerpo
           cuerpo[i].columna=cabeza.columna;
```

No se como hacer que avance en la dirección en la que se mueve mientras no toque las teclas que me cambian de dirección. Queria hacerlo dentro de la función entrada_de_usuario. Por ejemplo probé pero no funcioó con (antes del if(kbhit())):

```
   while(!=kbhit){ 
   if(*direccion=='w'){
      cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila-1;
      cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
      for(i=0;i<longitud_cuerpo;i++){
       cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila-1;
       cuerpo[i].columna=cabeza.columna;
        }
   if(*direccion=='s'){
                      ..instrucciones de avance..}
  etc..
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#define fil 20
#define col 20
void posicion_inicial_vibora();
void generar_comida(char matriz[][col]);
void bordear_matriz(char matriz[][col]);
void entrada_de_usuario(char *c,int fin,int puntos,char *direccion);
void comprobar_movimiento(char matriz[][col],int *longitud_cuerpo, int *fin,int *puntos);



typedef struct vibora{
    int fila;
    int columna;
}coordenada;

coordenada cuerpo[fil*col];
coordenada cabeza;

void posicion_inicial_vibora(){ //establece la posicion inical de la vibora


        cabeza.fila=9;

        cabeza.columna=10;

        cuerpo[0].fila=10;

        cuerpo[0].columna=10;


}

void generar_comida(char matriz[][col]){ //genera una posicion aleatoria para la comida
//comprueba que no hay nada en la posicion donde se creara la comida y si no hay nada la genera
    int posicion_aleatoria[2];
    int posicion_encontrada = 0;
    do{
           srand(time(NULL)); //no se si va adentro o afuera del do while, DONDE VAA???
       posicion_aleatoria[0] = rand() % fil;//devuelve el numero de fila, como disminuyo el valor max!!!!!-->(rand()-32747)%fil ??
       posicion_aleatoria[1] = rand() % col;//devuelve el numero de columna

    if(matriz[posicion_aleatoria[0]][posicion_aleatoria[1]] != '*' &&  //comprueba q no haya nada donde va a generarla y si no hay la genera
        matriz[posicion_aleatoria[0]][posicion_aleatoria[1]] != 'o'&&
        matriz[posicion_aleatoria[0]][posicion_aleatoria[1]] != '#' ){
             posicion_encontrada = 1;
             matriz[posicion_aleatoria[0]][posicion_aleatoria[1]] = '@';  //crea la comida representada con un @, f
    }

    }while(posicion_encontrada != 1);

}


void bordear_matriz(char matriz[][col]){
    int i,j;
    //rellenar la matriz
    for(i=0; i<fil; i++){
            for(j=0; j<col; j++){
                    if((i == 0) || (i == fil-1) || (j == 0) || (j == col-1)){
                     matriz[i][j] = '*';
                     }
                    if((i!=0)&&(i!=fil-1)&&(j!=0)&&(j!=col-1)){
                     matriz[i][j] = ' ';}

                    // printf("%c",matriz[i][j]); estos printf son de prueba para ver si me imprime la matriz..y si!!
                     }
          //  printf("\n");
    }



    //posiciones de la serpiente
    matriz[cabeza.fila][cabeza.columna] = 'o';
    matriz[cuerpo[0].fila][cuerpo[0].columna] = '#';

    generar_comida(matriz);
}
void entrada_de_usuario(char *c,int fin,int puntos,char *direccion){
    char matriz[fil][col]; 
    int longitud_cuerpo=1,i;

    fin=0,puntos=0; //esta bien inicializarlo aca?


    if(kbhit())
        {
        *c=getch();

        switch(*c){
            fflush(stdin);

            case 'w': if(*direccion!='s') {*direccion='w'; //ARRIBA
            // while(direccion='w'){ //creo q tengo q hacer un mientras(mientras no muera y no apriete otra direccion)
                                             //asi sigue en el bucle y repite para que avance.

              cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila-1;
              cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
                 for(i=0;i<longitud_cuerpo;i++){
                   cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila-1;
                   cuerpo[i].columna=cabeza.columna;
                   }
            comprobar_movimiento(matriz,&longitud_cuerpo,&fin,&puntos);

            break;

            case 's': if(*direccion!='w') {*direccion='s'; //ABAJO

               cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila+1;  //mueve cabeza
               cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
               for(i=0;i<longitud_cuerpo;i++){
               cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila+1;  //mueve cuerpo
               cuerpo[i].columna=cabeza.columna;
               }
            comprobar_movimiento(matriz,&longitud_cuerpo,&fin,&puntos);}

            break;

            case 'd': if(*direccion!='a') {*direccion='d'; //DERECHA

               cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna+1;
               cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila;
               for(i=0;i<longitud_cuerpo;i++){
               cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna+1;
               cuerpo[i].fila=cabeza.fila;
               }
            comprobar_movimiento(matriz,&longitud_cuerpo,&fin,&puntos);}

            break;

            case 'a': if(*direccion!='d'){ *direccion='a'; //IZQUIERDA

               cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna-1;
               cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila;
               for(i=0;i<longitud_cuerpo;i++){
               cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna-1;
               cuerpo[i].fila=cabeza.fila;
               }
            comprobar_movimiento(matriz,&longitud_cuerpo,&fin,&puntos);} 
            break;


        }
            }

    }
        }


void comprobar_movimiento(char matriz[][col],int *longitud_cuerpo, int *fin,int *puntos){ //ESTA FUNCION ME TIENE QUE DEVOLVER LO Q PONGO ABAJO
    int total_cuerpo=0,i=0; // no se inicializa el puntero *fin=0?? es necesario agregar *fin=0 en los casos en que no perdio??

//CUANDO ENTRO EN ESTA FUNCION, EN ALGUN IF, QUIERO Q ME DEVUELVA LAS MODIFICACIONES DE LOS CASOS Y FIN(0 O 1) PARA VER SI PERDI

    //COMPRUEBO SI EL SIGUIENTE MOVIENTO ES COMIDA
    if(matriz[cabeza.fila][cabeza.columna]=='@'){
            (*longitud_cuerpo)++;//creo q con esto se alarga
            total_cuerpo=total_cuerpo+1;
            matriz[cabeza.fila][cabeza.columna]='o';//con este la comida encontrada ahora es la cabeza del bicho
            for(i=0;i<(*longitud_cuerpo);i++){            //con este el cuerpo del bicho se fue actualizando y sumando
                matriz[cuerpo[i].fila][cuerpo[i].columna]='#';
            }

            matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]=' ';//con esto se supone que BORRA la ultima posición
            generar_comida(matriz);// cada vez q coma me va a generar una comida en una posicion nueva
           *puntos=*puntos+total_cuerpo*10;//sale del if,sale de la funcion y vuelva al entrada usuario
    }

    //COMPRUEBO SI EL SIGUIENTE MOVIMIENTO ES LA PARED
    if(matriz[cabeza.fila][cabeza.columna]=='*'){// puse LONGITUD_CUERPO como puntero, entonces en los for donde lo uso.. que va? ..for(..<=*longitud_cuerpo)???

        //entra por la pared de ARRIBA
        if((cabeza.fila==0)&&(cabeza.columna>=1)&&(cabeza.columna<=col-2)){
            cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila+(fil-1); //me posiciona la CABEZA en fila nro =>0+19=19(la ultima fila)
            cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
            for(i=0;i<(*longitud_cuerpo);i++){// con este for hasta el ultimo elemento del CUERPO me resta una posicion hasta que cada uno llegue a la pared
                cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila-1;
                cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna;
                matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]=' ';//con esto se supone que BORRA la ultima posición
                if(matriz[cuerpo[i].fila][cuerpo[i].columna]=='*'){//cuando cada elemento del cuerpo llega a la pared entra en este if,me mueve la cabeza una fila menos y me lleva a cada elemento a la ulitma fila
                    cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila-1; //mueve hacia ARRIBA la CABEZA
                    cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
                    cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila+(fil-1);//manda el cuerpo a la fila nro 19(la ultima)
                    cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna;
                    matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]='*';//con esto el ULTIMO elemento del cuerpo q llega a ser pared y pasa a la fila de abajo, sigue siendo la pared
                }
            }
        }

        //entra por la pared de la IZQUIERD
        if((cabeza.fila>=1)&&(cabeza.columna==0)&&(cabeza.fila<=fil-2)){
            cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna+(col-1); //me posiciona en columna nro=19(la ultima col)
            cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila;
            for(i=0;i<(*longitud_cuerpo);i++){
                cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna-1;
                cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila;
                matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]=' ';//con esto se supone que BORRA la ultima posición
                if(matriz[cuerpo[i].fila][cuerpo[i].columna]=='#'){
                    cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna-1;
                    cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila;
                    cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna+(col-1);
                    cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila;
                    matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]='*';//con esto el ULTIMO elemento del cuerpo q llega a ser pared y pasa a la fila de abajo, sigue siendo la pared
                }
            }
        }

        //entra por la pared de ABAJO
        if((cabeza.fila==fil-1)&&(cabeza.columna>=1)&&(cabeza.columna<=col-2)){
            cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila-(fil-1); //me posiciona en fila nro =>19-19=0(la primera fila)
            cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
            for(i=0;i<(*longitud_cuerpo);i++){
                cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila+1;
                cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna;
                matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]=' ';//con esto se supone que BORRA la ultima posición
                if(matriz[cuerpo[i].fila][cuerpo[i].columna]=='~'){
                    cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila+1; //mueve hacia ABAJO la CABEZA
                    cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna;
                    cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila-(fil-1);//manda el cuerpo a la fila nro 0(la primera)
                    cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna;
                    matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]='*';//con esto el ULTIMO elemento del cuerpo q llega a ser pared y pasa a la fila de abajo, sigue siendo la pared
                }
            }
        }

        //entra por la pared de la DERECHA
        if((cabeza.fila>=1)&&(cabeza.columna==col-1)&&(cabeza.fila<=fil-2)){
            cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna-(col-1); //me posiciona en columna nro=0(la primera col)
            cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila;
            for(i=0;i<(*longitud_cuerpo);i++){
                cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna+1;
                cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila;
                matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]=' ';//con esto se supone que BORRA la ultima posición
                if(matriz[cuerpo[i].fila][cuerpo[i].columna]=='~'){
                    cabeza.columna=cabeza.columna+1;//mueve hacia la DERECHA la CABEZA
                    cabeza.fila=cabeza.fila;
                    cuerpo[i].columna=cuerpo[i].columna-(col-1);//manda cada elemento del cuerpo a la col nro=0
                    cuerpo[i].fila=cuerpo[i].fila;
                    matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]='*';//con esto el ULTIMO elemento del cuerpo q llega a ser pared y pasa a la fila de abajo, sigue siendo la pared
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //COMPRUEBO SI EL SIGUIENTE MOVIMIENTO EN " " (NADA)
    if(matriz[cabeza.fila][cabeza.columna]==' '){

       matriz[cabeza.fila][cabeza.columna]='o';//con este la "nada" encontrada ahora es la cabeza del bicho
      for(i=0;i<(*longitud_cuerpo);i++){            //con este el cuerpo del bichose fue actualizando y sumando,creo q es longitud_cuerpo
       matriz[cuerpo[i].fila][cuerpo[i].columna]='#';
            }
      matriz[cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].fila][cuerpo[(*longitud_cuerpo)].columna]=' ';//con esto se BORRA la ultima posicion
    }

    //COMPRUEBO SI EL SIGUIENTE MOVIMIENTO ES EL CUERPO "~",ENTONCES PERDIO
    if(matriz[cabeza.fila][cabeza.columna]=='~'){
            *fin=1;
    }


}



int main(){
    char matriz[fil][col],c,direccion='w';//inicializa direccion en el main pero despues la otra funcion que la usa me la modifica
    int fin=0,puntos=0,i,j;


   posicion_inicial_vibora();
   bordear_matriz(matriz);

   do{

     entrada_de_usuario(&c,fin,puntos,&direccion);
     Sleep(500);
     system("cls");
     for(i=0;i<fil;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("%c",matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        //Sleep(500);
     }
   }while(fin!=1);

   if(fin==1){
    printf("PARTIDA PERDIDA\n");
    printf("PUNTUACION: %i",puntos);
   }


    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que queres decir con que no sabes como hacer que avance? Agregaste todo tu codigo y es dificil que alguien pueda ayudarte sin saber donde tenes el problema. por favor mira [mcve].

Comment: con que no avance quiero decir que no se mueve, imprime siempre en la misma posición la viborita. En la funcion entrada_de _usuario segun la tecla que toque(por ej w=arriba) me tendria que cambiar la posicion una fila arriba, pero no se como escribir que mientras no toque ninguna tecla se mueva en la direccion en la que está. Ahi edité lo que escribí para ver si se puedo hacerme entender mejor

Comment: De entrada, no me he leido todo el código que adjuntas, pero viendo cuál es el problema que indicas en tu comentario, lo que necesitas es que cuando se pulse una tecla, en lugar de mover la vívora simplemente guardes en una variable la dirección en que apuntará su cabeza (puede ser otro campo de la estructura `vivora`). Otra función distinta será la que la mueva en esa dirección. En el bucle principal llamas primero a la entrada del usuario y después a la que mueve la vívora. De este modo se moverá en cada iteración del bucle

Comment: que raro que no te lea el código.. pero bueno mas o menos entendi tu explicacion, yo en la funcion entrada_de_usuario use if(kbhit())..con eso entendia yo que reconoce si toco una tecla, lo otro es que traté de hacer una funcion aparte para que se mueva (con las instrucciones que estan dentro de los "case")pero de ninguna de las formas en que la puse se movia por eso las borré, no encuentro la forma de hacer que se mueva por lo menos una vez. Igual muchas gracias por tu comentario! voy a seguir intentando con crear esa función que la mueva.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es complicado de seguir y analizar (En un vistazo rápido ya he podido ver algo que no compila), mas aún cuando tu problema es muy concreto pero no acotas en el código dónde está el problema... pero si lo entiendo bien tu problema no es de código si no de concepto:

> No se como hacer que avance en la dirección en la que se mueve mientras no toque las teclas que me cambian de dirección.

Esta operación puede ser bastante sencilla si usas una `coordenada` para representar el movimiento:

- Cuando el movimiento es de izquierda a derecha, `fila` será 0 y `columna` será 1.
- Cuando el movimiento es de arriba a abajo, `fila` será 1 y `columna` será 0.
- Cuando el movimiento es de derecha a izquierda, `fila` será 0 y `columna` será -1.
- Cuando el movimiento es de abajo a arriba, `fila` será -1 y `columna` será 0.

Con esta sencilla premisa, en cada ciclo de juego podrás calcular la siguiente posición de la cabeza sumando los componentes a la posición actual:

```
coordenada siguiente;
siguiente.fila = cabeza.fila + direccion.fila;
siguiente.columna = cabeza.columna + direccion.columna;
```

El `coordenada direccion` se mantiene igual hasta que pulsas una tecla, en cuyo caso cambia según las normas prestablecidas:

```
switch(*c) {
    case 'w': case 'W':
        direccion.fila = -1;
        direccion.columna = 0;
        break;
    case 'a': case 'A':
        direccion.fila = 0;
        direccion.columna = -1;
        break;
    case 's': case 'S':
        direccion.fila = 1;
        direccion.columna = 0;
        break;
    case 'd': case 'D':
        direccion.fila = 0;
        direccion.columna = 1;
        break;
}
```

La lógica detrás de esta propuesta consiste en que la víbora avanza siempre en la dirección que la estructura `direccion` marca y esta dirección cambia al pulsar teclas.